# Convert 10 digit number from Legacy system to Date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, time, unix-timestamp

I am converting data from a legacy system to SQL. I got to convert a 10 digit number (e.g. 1419120000) to SQL DateTime. I am able to do so using `dateadd(second,1419120000,'1970-01-01')`. This function returns '2014-12-21 00:00:00.000'. However, in the UI of the legacy system it shows '12/20/2022' for the same value. So, the mentioned number (1419120000) supposed to be '12/20/2022'.

Can anyone please help me to get '12/20/2022' from 1419120000.

Comment: I mean, `select dateadd(second,1419120000,'1977-12-31')` will give you the desired output for that single value but there's no way to know if that's the correct pattern with the info you've given

Comment: select dateadd(second,-1419120000,'20221220') returns 12/31/1977 don't know if that helps

Comment: Apparently TRIPOS and some descendants (most famously AmigaOS) used 1978-01-01 as their epoch, so it's conceivable that's what your legacy system is doing - https://www.reddit.com/r/amiga/comments/10b0gij/why_is_epoch_19780101/

Comment: In addition to the 8 years which are explained above, consider some hours difference from localistion. You are trying converting the epoch time to a specific local time. First you should find out what is the correct local time. Then you have to add or substract the corresponding number of hours to UTC.

There is the additional complication of daylight savings which might have to be considered, depending on the local conditions

This tool here for checking the conversion from and to epoch time might be useful:

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Here is a [list of epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)), and AmigaOS has, as slothrop mentioned, 1978-01-01 which is probably what you need.